# How to select the filtered data without including the column names using excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

Below is the code that I came up with, however, the issue lies in the 3rd line wherein the filtered data does not necessarily start in row 2. If the first data point satisfying the criteria is located at row 150, then it would return an error:

[image: Error]

```
Total_Rows_Compiled = Worksheets("Compiled").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Compiled").Range("$A$1:$G$52818").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(l, 1)
Worksheets("Compiled").Range("A2:G" & Total_Rows_Compiled).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the `Areas`:

```
    Dim filterRange As Range, filteredRange As Range, area As Range

    Set filterRange = Worksheets("Compiled").Range("$A$1:$G$52818")
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(l, 1)

    Set filteredRange = Intersect(filterRange, filterRange.Offset(1, 0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'remove headers

    If Not filteredRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each area In filteredRange.Areas
            'do something with area
            Debug.Print area.Address
        Next area
    End If
```

---

The following data, when filtered on "test", returns the ranges (areas) `B2:F2` and `B4:F5` as required

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be anything substantially wrong with your code. With that in mind, the following is a combination of methods that I have found to be reasonably error free.

```
with Worksheets("Compiled")
    .activate
    if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false
    Total_Rows_Compiled = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    with .range("A1:G" & Total_Rows_Compiled)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(l, 1)
        with .resize(.rows.count-1, .columns.count).offset(1, 0)
            if cbool(application.subtotal(103, .cells)) then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            end if
        end with
    end with
end with
```

Comment: I have only included .Activate because you cannot .Select cells that are not on the active sheet. If your ultimate purpose is to do something other than Select the visible cells then .Activate can be removed.

Comment: I literally don't have a clue what subtotal is doing there!? (read: I'd really like to know!)

Comment: non-destructive count of visible values. If at least 1 visible cell has a value, it proceeds. I prefer this over testing if .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) is Not Nothing.